# Is there a prerequisite to running a Linux Docker container on a Windows machine?

Tags: linux, docker

Installed **Docker 19.03.0** on a **Windows 10** Machine.  I can start it with Windows Containers but as soon as I "switch to Linux containers" it fails with:

```
> Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException: Unhandled exception: job failed
> with message: The operation failed.    at
> Docker.Core.Logging.ClientExceptionInterceptor.<InterceptResponseAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\ClientExceptionInterceptor.cs:line
> 17
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> Docker.Core.Logging.LoggingMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\LoggingMessageHandler.cs:line
> 37
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Docker.Core.BackendAPI.BackendAPIClient.<CreateHyperVVMAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\BackendAPIClient.cs:line
> 93
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Docker.Engines.LinuxHyperVEngine.<DoStartAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\LinuxHyperVEngine.cs:line
> 57
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line
> 29
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line
> 67
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line
> 92 Original stacktrace:    at
> Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.HandleUpdatedJob(CIMConcreteJob
> updatedJob) in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line
> 800    at
> Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<HandleMaybeAsyncJob>d__37.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line
> 740
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<CreateDefaultVMAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line
> 126
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<CreateOrConfigureDockerVMAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line
> 97
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Docker.Backend.HyperV.<CreateOrConfigureAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperV.cs:line
> 131
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.HyperVAPIController.<CreateVMAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\HyperVAPIController.cs:line
> 35
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto "